# How to safely reinterpret Vec<f64> as Vec<num_complex::Complex<f64>> with half the size?

Tags: rust, unsafe

I have complex number data filled into a `Vec<f64>` by an external C library (prefer not to change) in the form `[i_0_real, i_0_imag, i_1_real, i_1_imag, ...]` and it appears that this `Vec<f64>` has the same memory layout as a `Vec<num_complex::Complex<f64>>` of half the length would be, given that `num_complex::Complex<f64>`'s data structure is memory-layout compatible with `[f64; 2]` as documented [here](https://rust-num.github.io/num/num_complex/struct.Complex.html). I'd like to use it as such without needing a re-allocation of a potentially large buffer.

I'm assuming that it's valid to use `from_raw_parts()` in `std::vec::Vec` to fake a new `Vec` that takes ownership of the old `Vec`'s memory (by forgetting the old `Vec`) and use `size / 2` and `capacity / 2`, but that requires unsafe code. Is there a "safe" way to do this kind of data re-interpretation?

The `Vec` is allocated in Rust as a `Vec<f64>` and is populated by a C function using `.as_mut_ptr()` that fills in the `Vec<f64>`.

My current compiling unsafe implementation:

```
extern crate num_complex;

pub fn convert_to_complex_unsafe(mut buffer: Vec<f64>) -> Vec<num_complex::Complex<f64>> {
    let new_vec = unsafe {
        Vec::from_raw_parts(
            buffer.as_mut_ptr() as *mut num_complex::Complex<f64>,
            buffer.len() / 2,
            buffer.capacity() / 2,
        )
    };
    std::mem::forget(buffer);
    return new_vec;
}

fn main() {
    println!(
        "Converted vector: {:?}",
        convert_to_complex_unsafe(vec![3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0])
    );
}
```

Comment: `f64` is not a complex in C

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Is there a "safe" way to do this kind of data re-interpretation?

No. At the very least, this is because the information you need to know is not expressed in the Rust type system but is expressed via prose (a.k.a. the docs):

> `Complex<T>` is memory layout compatible with an array `[T; 2]`.
>
> — [`Complex` docs](https://rust-num.github.io/num/num_complex/struct.Complex.html)

> If a `Vec` has allocated memory, then [...] its pointer points to `len` initialized, contiguous elements in order (what you would see if you coerced it to a slice),
>
> — [`Vec` docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#guarantees)

> Arrays coerce to slices (`[T]`)
>
> — [Array docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html)

Since a `Complex` is memory-compatible with an array, an array's data is memory-compatible with a slice, and a `Vec`'s data is memory-compatible with a slice, this transformation should be safe, even though the compiler cannot tell this.

This information should be attached (via a comment) to your unsafe block.

I *would* make some small tweaks to your function:

- Having two `Vec`s at the same time pointing to the same data makes me *very* nervous. This can be trivially avoided by introducing some variables and forgetting one before creating the other.
- Remove the `return` keyword to be more idiomatic
- Add some asserts that the starting length of the data is a multiple of two.
- As [rodrigo points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54185667/how-to-safely-reinterpret-vecf64-as-vecnum-complexcomplexf64-with-half-t/54188098?noredirect=1#comment95225988_54188098), the capacity could easily be an odd number. To attempt to avoid this, we call [`shrink_to_fit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.shrink_to_fit). This has the downside that the `Vec` *may* need to reallocate and copy the memory, depending on the implementation.
- Expand the `unsafe` block to cover all of the related code that is required to ensure that the safety invariants are upheld.

```
pub fn convert_to_complex(mut buffer: Vec<f64>) -> Vec<num_complex::Complex<f64>> {
    // This is where I'd put the rationale for why this `unsafe` block
    // upholds the guarantees that I must ensure. Too bad I
    // copy-and-pasted from Stack Overflow without reading this comment!
    unsafe {
        buffer.shrink_to_fit();

        let ptr = buffer.as_mut_ptr() as *mut num_complex::Complex<f64>;
        let len = buffer.len();
        let cap = buffer.capacity();

        assert!(len % 2 == 0);
        assert!(cap % 2 == 0);

        std::mem::forget(buffer);

        Vec::from_raw_parts(ptr, len / 2, cap / 2)
    }
}
```

To avoid all the worrying about the capacity, you could just convert a slice into the `Vec`. This also doesn't have any extra memory allocation. It's simpler because we can "lose" any odd trailing values because the `Vec` still maintains them.

```
pub fn convert_to_complex(buffer: &[f64]) -> &[num_complex::Complex<f64>] {
    // This is where I'd put the rationale for why this `unsafe` block
    // upholds the guarantees that I must ensure. Too bad I
    // copy-and-pasted from Stack Overflow without reading this comment!
    unsafe {
        let ptr = buffer.as_ptr() as *const num_complex::Complex<f64>;
        let len = buffer.len();

        assert!(len % 2 == 0);
        
        std::slice::from_raw_parts(ptr, len / 2)
    }
}
```

Comment: Wish I could give another +1 for the codes comment.

Comment: What makes me slightly nervous is the `assert!(cap % 2 == 0);` because the capacity is not usually managed by the user, and it could inadvertently be odd and crash the program. I would prefer a function such as `as_complex_unsafe(buffer: &[f64] -> &[Complex<f64>]` so that no capacity is involved.

Comment: @rodrigo great points. I skipped the slice answer because OP specifically requested about `Vec`, but you are right that it should be included. Updated to handle odd capacities as well.

Comment: Good points all on odd capacity - I did built parallel implementations for `&[f64]` and `&mut [f64]`, perhaps it's better to make these the only conversions allowed.

Comment: Say @Shepmaster, is the reason why you don't want two `Vec`s pointing to the same memory because if a terminate/panic happens elsewhere, there's a chance that unwinding from this thread if the execution is before the `std::mem::forget()` will cause a double-free?

Comment: @jv-dev in this specific case, yes. The original code can't have this problem as there's no code between the creation and the `forget`, but it could easily happen with a bit of refactoring over time.